# Azure DevOps / Multiple projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, cicd

I'm trying to get CICD ready using Azure DevOps. I have a big repo with 1 webapp, 2 azure functions and some others projects used as librairies. So I have 3 project to deploy, on different environnements.

I have only 1 .sln file, at the root of these projects.

I'm able to build all the projects, but I don't know how to get 1 particular built project (artifact ?) and deploy it.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'allproject.sln'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

I tried this, and I'm able to deploy the artifact on my release pipeline but when I have only one project built. Here I don't know how to procede.

Splitting my projects and create solution for each projects is a possibility, but if possible I would avoid this. Use MSBuild is possible too but I really want to avoid it because of the complexity (in the maintenance of the pipelines, we are a small team).

---

After GeralexGR awesome answer, I solved some of my problems but I cant solve the publication of the artifacts.

[Here a screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIbUw.png)

So I want to publish functionApp on the function app env, but I cant choose the artifact on the publication interface. Any idea ?

Comment: Thanks for GeralexGR's answer. I checked your question as well as GeralexGR's answer and found that it is indeed an effective method. Please follow his steps and methods to try it first. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to answer them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a solution based on your description. In this setup I included a consoleApp and two functions apps inside the functions folder as shown below.

[image: project hierarchy]

You can build your project as you could do on visual studio and each project will contain the output bin and obj folders with the artifact.

[image: build azure devops]

You should then decide your strategy regarding how you should proceed. For example you could upload all ArtifactsStagingDirectory or each folder separate.

**YAML pipeline:**

```
trigger:
- none

pr: none 

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: '6.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Building .NET project
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration debug'
```

Test step to locate the structure:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      cd "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s"
      ls
```

Inside functions and consoleapp projects you can locate the build artifacts.

[image: test-step]

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer. I updated my subject with a new problem.

Comment: @Showb If you find an answer helpful consider making a thumbs up for the author it helps with the reputation. Regarding the function app, do you use the functions app builtin task? It needs some values like the Azure subscription, app type, name and also the location of your package or folder. There you should select `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/functions/functionapp2/bin/debug` for example.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think the problem I have is I don't know what I should publish. When a Ise the wizard for a single app, all is automatically choosed. But here I have tu manually select the files I want to publish. I found a file names webappname.dll so I tried to puslish it but it's not working. Do you have a suggestion to better understand what are the files to publish ? Should I publish a folder ? Is the zip automatically created ? Sorry for all this newbie's questions... I used .net since a long time but I never had to manage the deployment, it's totally new for me